# Django model property is not working - Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I'm facing a issue with while trying to define a property in Django model and access them. I have 2 models first one is product and second one is product attributes. Product attributes has several field like Color and Brand. I want to create properties to get the product's brand and color for usage in template and filtering( django-filter) but property in model not giving result as expected. Please find the below codes and remarks for your reference and help.

Product Model :

```
class Product(models.Model):
measurement_choices = (('Liter', 'Liter'), ('Kilogram', 'Kilogram'), ('Cloth', 'Cloth'), ('Shoe', 'Shoe'))
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
sku = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
stock = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
measurement = models.CharField(choices=measurement_choices, max_length=20, null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
discounted_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', default='product.png', null=True, blank=True)
image_one = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_two = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_three = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_four = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_five = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
null=True,related_name='+')
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('Active', 'Active'), ('Inactive', 
'Inactive')))
history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Property i have created to get the brand name:

```
def p_brand(self):
    brand = ''
    all_attributes = self.productattribute_set.all()
    for att in all_attributes:
        brand = att.brand.title
        print(brand)
    return brand
```

This property is returning below result in view instead of brand title:

```
   <bound method Product.p_brand of <Product: 1:T-Shirt:Men>>
   <bound method Product.p_brand of <Product: 2:Shoe:Men>>
   <bound method Product.p_brand of <Product: 3:Book:Men>>
```

Product attribute model :

```
class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
      blank=True)
     color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
      blank=True)
      size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
      price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
      offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
      blank=True)
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_imgs/", null=True, blank=True)
      history = HistoricalRecords()
```

I have also tried to get brand in view using below method which is working fine.

```
for product in Product.objects.all():
    attr = product.productattribute_set.all()
    for att in attr:
    print(att.brand.title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not make it a property, this is a simple method. You need to add the [**`@property`** decorator [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    
    @property  # ← property decorator
    def p_brand(self):
        return ', '.join(
            pa.brand.title
            for pa in self.productattribute_set.select_related('brand')
        )
```

Comment: Now can i use this property to filter products using django-filter?

Comment: @Kuldeep: no, since properties do not exist at the database side.